# javascript: site passing object to setinterval

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to modify `setInterval` on a website using Greasemonkey. My code looks like this:

```
// @run-at         document-start

(function() {
    var clearIntervalOriginal = unsafeWindow.clearInterval;
    unsafeWindow.clearInterval = function(foo) {
        GM_log(typeof foo + ":" + foo)
        clearIntervalOriginal(foo);
    }
}());
```

Example [website](http://tv.yahoo.com/news/former-miss-new-hampshire-usa-faces-assault-charge.html).

If you look at console log you'll see that the interval ID number isn't there and instead `foo` is sometimes an object. Looking at site source, I think this is the relevant code being used:

```
//yahoo code
i.tid=c.setInterval(function(){
    if(i.done){
        c.clearTimeout(i.tid);
        i.rec=[i.t_render-h,i.t_jsload-h,i.t_jsinit-h,i.t_jsend-h,i.t_jsend-i.t_jsinit]
    }
},f);
```

How can I get the interval ID number from `foo` object?

Comment: You're the one who can see what `console.log` outputs. Based on whatever that is, this should be trivial to answer for yourself.

Comment: What does `c` reference in the second piece of code? In the first bit, `clearInterval` is replaced (which is not a good strategy to start with), then later `clearTimeout` is called. Is that intended? As Nick says, the timer reference is in `i.tid`, so that is what you need to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Am I reading your code wrong, or is your clearIntervalOriginal function recursively calling itself ad infinitum?

In the Yahoo code, the i.tid is the interval id. If you want to cancel the interval, you need to supply that id. For example:

```
clearInterval(i.tid);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval